# Handle json array in javascript with loop

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have json array like this:

```
     {"error":false,
 "message":"",
 "Album_list":[{"Album":{"id":"27","user_id":"46","title":"Internal","status":"1","time":"","created":"2016-05-02 17:20:27","modified":"2016-05-02 17:20:27"}},
    {"Album":{"id":"30","user_id":"46","title":"efdrhty","status":"1","time":"","created":"2016-05-04 08:52:12","modified":"2016-05-04 08:52:12"}},
    {"Album":{"id":"37","user_id":"46","title":"external","status":"1","time":"","created":"2016-05-06 08:04:55","modified":"2016-05-06 08:04:55"}},
    {"Album":{"id":"38","user_id":"46","title":"James Jobs" ,"status":"1","time":"","created":"2016-05-17 09:40:41","modified":"2016-05-17 09:40:41"}},
    {"Album":{"id":"41","user_id":"46","title":"17th May 2016","status":"1","time":"","created":"2016-05-17 10:20 :10","modified":"2016-05-17 10:20:10"}}]}
```

Now, in `success` function i need this `Album_list` data in a loop.

I try this but i can't get it correctly

Javascript code:

```
success: function (response) {

            if (response.error == true) {
                console.log(response.message);
            } else {
                content += '<div class="ui-grid-b gallery-sec">';

                for (img in response.Album_list) {
                    console.log(img);  

                    content += '<div class="ui-block-b gallery-sec">' +
                        '<div class="gallery-thumb-col">' +
                        '<div class="gallery-thumb">' +
                        '<img src="images/blue-box-logo.png" alt="">' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="full">' +
                        '<h2>'+img.Album.title+'</h2>' +  //I need the title of album here
                    '</div>' +
                    '<p>2 Photos</p>' +
                    '<div class="ftr-bg">' +
                        '<i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>';

                }
                content += '</div>';
                $('#gallery .page-content').html(content);

            }
        }
```

`console.log(img);` gives 0, then 1, then upto 4. but i need `Album` array here.

Comment: Do not use for in for arrays. Use regular for i loop or forEach if possible.

Comment: I tried forEach loop but it's not working in javascript

Comment: Loop doesn't matter, I just want to know how to get `Album` array

Comment: Album is an object. Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.Album_list.length; i++) {
   var album = response.Album_list[i];

   console.log(album);
}
```

[Documentation about for in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Since I saw you're using jQuery. You can do this:

```
$.each(response.Album_list, function(index, album) {
    console.log(album);
});
```

Comment: You're awesome. keep it up.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
for (img in response.Album_list) {
    // code here
}
```

with

```
response.Album_list.forEach(function (img) {
    // code here
});
```

Because your `img` is not an element, but the variable for the index.

Comment: forEach is not supported in all browser though. But I think it is cleaner so if possible use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try :

```
for (var index in response.Album_list) {
    img = response.Album_list[index];

    // rest of the code as it it
}
```

Comment: Do not use this if order is important. Arrays are used because order is relevant and the use of for in cannot ensure that it will loop in order!

Comment: In general do not use for in for arrays.